# Laplace equation in square region

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose we have square region with side $l$ and rectangular with sides $l$ and $l+e$, $e=0.001$.

```
l = 10; e = 0.001;
squareReg = DiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, l}]];
rectReg = DiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, l + e}]];
```

The eigenfunctions of Laplace operator in this region are known

```
realSol[x_, y_, {n1_, n2_}, l_] := Sin[(\[Pi]*n1)/l*x]*Sin[(\[Pi]*n2)/l*y]
```

where `n1` and `n2` are integers. However the numerical solution looks strange.

```
   ndSol = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}], 
    DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, True]},
   f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] squareReg, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" ->
      {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05, 
          AccuracyGoal -> 4}}}}];
DensityPlot[ndSol[[2, 7]]^2, {x, y} \[Element] squareReg , PlotPoints -> 80]
```

None of the real solutions

```
DensityPlot[realSol[x, y, {2, 3}, l]^2, {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

looks like numerical one. Also the interesting thing here is that the solution looks ok for slightly rectangular (non-square region).

```
ndSolRect = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}], 
    DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, True]},
   f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] rectReg, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" ->
      {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05, 
          AccuracyGoal -> 4}}}}];
DensityPlot[ndSolRect[[2, 7]]^2, {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
 PlotPoints -> 80]
```

I have played with smaller mesh and with `e` and still don't understand this.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Shouldn't the solution be exactly zero? I suggest to simplify things. If I NDSolve the problem without using NDEigensystem and Refrain from Options the solution looks fine, also for non trivial right hand sides of the Laplace equation,

Comment: These are Laplace operator eigen-functions for the square region. So, its not the really Laplace equation its Hemgoltz one (lap(f)==k^2*f). The question is that DEigensystem gives exact solutions which are different from the NDEigensystem solutions.